# Is orientability a local or global property?

Tags: differential-geometry

That is the question in essence. The first definition of orientability is the following:

> A regular surface $S$ is called orientable if it is possible to cover it with a family of coordinate neighborhoods in such a way that if a point $p\in S$ belongs to two neigborhoods of this family, then the change of coordinates has positive Jacobian at $p$. The choice of such a family is called an orientation of $S$, and $S$, in this case, is called oriented. If such a choice is not possible, the surface is called nonorientable.

Well, what if we cover $S$ with only one coordinate neigborhood? Then (I think) the surface is always orientable and this would be a global property of the surface. 
This is what my intuition tells me, but how do I formalize this argument?

Comment: What does it mean for a property to be global or local in this context? For example, differentiability is local because it is a pointwise property.

Comment: You have local orientations which may or may not assemble correctly to give a global orientation.

Comment: Also, I wouldn't be shocked if surfaces with one coordinate chart were all orientable.  They're probably all diffeo to $\mathbb{R}^2$, right?  I don't know many interesting surfaces for which one chart suffices.

Comment: @rubikscube09 What I understand is that a local property is one that is satisfied in a neighborhood of $p$. But since we talk about orientability of a surface and not of a patch of a surface, that's where I am getting confused.

Comment: @Randall That's where I am confused. I haven't heard of "local orientations" but rather, orientation of the whole surface.